# Smart quotes in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

We can enable/disable smart quotes for many apps by going to Edit → Substitutions. However, In Google Chrome, “Substitutions” does not exist. When searching online, though, it seems that it might’ve existed at some point, as I find multiple posts on how to disable the feature.

Is it no longer available (and if so why) or is it something on my side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As claimed by [this issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=444603), text substitution appears to have been disabled due to a bug:

> Text replacement was originally disabled due to http://crbug.com/173405 but Apple has since fixed the root cause of the issue.

[Another issue](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=42434) is open to track progress on the feature.